# Different behaviour of dialog nodes in watson console and mobile app

Tags: android, ibm-cloud, watson-conversation, watson, watson-dialog

I have created few dialogs in the watson console and in try it out panel the nodes are traversed by in proper way by giving priority to child nodes but in android app (watson android sample) it gives priority to the outer nodes.

Why there is a different behaviour in try it out panel and android application?

Comment: Are you sure that the same input is transferred to Conversation? Can you give examples for the input and what should be matched?

Comment: yes I am sure that the same input is passed. Same works perfect in "try it out" panel but its behaves different in android app. If I add multiple nodes with their multiple child nodes the flow in android app gets disturbed but works perfect in try it out panel.

Comment: For example :
Android :- I need a cadillac car in black color (Here car, cadillac and black are entities)
Watson : Ok will proceed your request.

but if ANdroid says :- I need a cadillac car (No color mentioned) 
here I am adding the child node named color to get the color input from user. But If I have already created one outer node named color, instead 
of calling the color child node, the outer child node gets called in android app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is that you are not reusing the session context and starting a new session for each call into Conversation. You need to send the session context that is returned from Conversation together with the new input back to Conversation. Thus, the dialog can be picked up at the node where it left. The API calls are stateless and you need to provide it as part of the call.

Comment: You are right, I was not reusing the context. Thank u, now it is working for me :-)